# How to add Server control into Checkboxlist

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, checkboxlist

I try to add the Server Control (Hyperlink) into my current checkboxlist(Already bonded from database). Here is code. It's executed but control not rendered and show into Checkboxlist.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chkAttribute.Items.Cast<ListItem>().ToList().ForEach(s =>
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink h = new HyperLink();
            h.Text = s.Value;
            string url = "~/Default.aspx?Item=" + Server.UrlEncode(s.Value);
            h.NavigateUrl = url;
            chkAttribute.Controls.Add(h);

        });
    }
```

What is wrong in it. If I check the controls into immediate window then it will show the control added but not showing on page.

Answer (score 0):

No, the `HyperLink` control won't be rendered in a CheckBoxList.

The issue is not limit to `HyperLink` control but all of the others except for `ListItem` control: when we write the code to add a control, which is not a `ListItem`, into a `ListControl` like `CheckBoxList` or `DropDownList`, even though framework will return no exception, the control we added will not be displayed as well.

The reason why it could be happened is that when the `ListControl` renders its contents, only `ListItem` control will be written to the page, the other kind of controls will be ignored. Much like something demonstrated below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
{
   if ((this.Controls(i)) is ListItem)
   {
      //Render 
   }
}
```

You may note that the Controls collection is merely a data collection. It’s totally up to the container to render them or not. If you turn on 'Trace' option in the page directive, you will see the Literal control you added is a node of the `CheckBoxList`: it’s just not rendering to the html at all.

Comment: Check this link... Here they add the Label  http://forums.asp.net/t/1383931.aspx/1    http://forums.asp.net/t/1611395.aspx/1

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi I have seen that link and they are adding that label to a `PlaceHolder (PlaceHolder1)` control not to `CheckBoxList (cblManufacturer or cblModels)` controls

Comment: :Thanks yogi...So I need to change my design.My plan to add one hyperlink with the text of checkbox. U have any idea then please tell me.

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi For that you should create a custom `User Control`, And `Control.Add` accepts all type since it's not the method in `CheckBoxList` class if you'll go up the inheritance hierarchy you'll find that its `Control` class which has this property so its common for all `WebControl` classes.